# Laravel 6.8 return 404 not found page

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404

My laravel returning 404 page not found for all pages except for '/'. 
Below are my routes.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/hello', function () {
    return '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
});
```

This is my url
`http://localhost/cultural-heritagedp/public/hello`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Route::get('/hello', function () {
    return "Hello World";
});
```

Then

```
php artisan route:list
```

**start a development server by running the following in your command line**

```
php artisan serve
```

**after that try browsing to**

```
localhost:8000
```

*and then*

```
localhost:8000/hello
```